# Converting arm code to use NEON intrinsics

Tags: arm, neon, beagleboard, intrinsics, cortex-a8

I have been trying to modify the code beneath to work with NEON Intrinsics, thereby creating a speedup. Unfortunately nothing seems to work correctly. Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong? I updated the doubles to single floating point elements.

```
typedef         float       REAL;
typedef         REAL        VEC3[3];    

typedef struct  driehoek
{
    VEC3        norm;                   /* Face normal. */
    REAL        d;                      /* Plane equation D. */
    VEC3        *vptr;                  /* Global vertex list pointer. */
    VEC3        *nptr;                  /* Global normal list pointer. */
    INT         vindex[3];              /* Index of vertices. */
    INT         indx;                   /* Normal component max flag. */
    BOOL        norminterp;             /* Do normal interpolation? */
    BOOL        vorder;                 /* Vertex order orientation. */
}driehoek;

typedef struct element
{
    INT         index;
    struct object   *parent;            /* Ptr back to parent object.    */
    CHAR        *data;                  /* Pointer to data info.         */
    BBOX        bv;                     /* Element bounding volume.      */
}ELEMENT;

INT TriangleIntersection(RAY *pr, ELEMENT *pe, IRECORD *hit)
{
    FLOAT      Rd_dot_Pn;       /* Polygon normal dot ray direction. */
    FLOAT      Ro_dot_Pn;       /* Polygon normal dot ray origin.    */
    FLOAT      q1, q2;
    FLOAT      tval;            /* Intersection t distance value.    */
    VEC3       *v1, *v2, *v3;       /* Vertex list pointers.         */
    VEC3       e1, e2, e3;      /* Edge vectors.             */
    driehoek   *pt;         /* Ptr to triangle data.         */


    pt = (driehoek *)pe->data;

    Rd_dot_Pn = VecDot(pt->norm, pr->D);

    if (ABS(Rd_dot_Pn) < RAYEPS)        /* Ray is parallel.      */
        return (0);

        hit->b3 = e1[0] * (q2 - (*v1)[1]) - e1[1] * (q1 - (*v1)[0]);
        if (!INSIDE(hit->b3, pt->norm[2]))
            return (0);
        break;
    }

    return (1);
 }
```

Comment: How do you use NEON Intrinsics? You don't use any of it in your code so far.

Answer (score 4):

An array of `float vec[3]` is not enough of a hint to the compiler that **NEON** intrinsic can be used.  The issue is that `float vec[3]` has each element individually addressable.  The compiler must store each in a floating point register.  See [*gcc NEON intrinsic*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) documentation.

Although *3 dimensions* is very common in this Universe, our friends the computers like binary.  So you have two data types that can be used for **NEON** intrinsics; `float32x4_t` and `float32x2_t`.  You need to use the intrinsics such as `vfmaq_f32`, `vsubq_f32`, etc.  These intrinsics are different for each compiler; I guess you are using `gcc`.  You should  only use the intrinsic data types as combining `float32x2_t` with a single `float` can result in movement between register types, which is expensive.  If your algorithm can treat each dimension separately, then you might be able to combine types.  However, I don't think you will have *register* pressure and the *SIMD* speed-up should be beneficial.  I would keep everything in `float32x4_t` to begin with.  You maybe able to use the extra dimension for [3D-projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection) when it comes to the rendering phase.

Here is the [source](https://code.google.com/archive/p/math-neon/source/default/source) to a **cmath** library called [*math-neon*](http://code.google.com/p/math-neon/) under LGPL.  Instead of using *intrinsics* with *gcc*, it uses inline assembler.<sup>[Neon intrinsics vs assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828567/arm-neon-intrinsics-vs-hand-assembly)</sup>

See also: [*armcc* NEON intrinsics](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0348c/Badcdfad.html), if you are using the ARM compiler.

Comment: [OpenCV Neon Intrinscis](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/intrin_neon.hpp) has an implementation, but it is more complex to understand as it gives an API for AVX/SSE and other SIMD instruction sets.